# Control to use to display a n number of items from a list

Tags: c#, list, class, controls, items

I've a medical intervention list on my class Patient which I am able to add the medical interventions the patient had which can be many.
Though, I want to be able to search for the patient id and show all the medical interventions the patient had in a control. I've been trying listBox but it doesn't seem like the correct option, plus I don't know how to add the items of the list into the control.
My code when adding a medical intervention:

```
        foreach (Paciente patient in pacientes)
        {
            if (patient.id == Convert.ToInt32(txtIDI.Text))
            {
                patient.intervencoes.Add(txtIntervencaoI.Text);
                adicionarI = true;
                break;
            }
```

And when I'm searching for the id and displaying all the other info:

```
       bool found = false;
        foreach (Paciente patient in pacientes)
        {
            if (patient.id == Convert.ToInt32(txtIDP.Text))
            {
                txtNomeP.Text = patient.nome;
                txtIdadeP.Text = Convert.ToString(patient.idade);
                txtMoradaP.Text = patient.morada;
                txtContatoP.Text = patient.contato;
                txtEmailP.Text = patient.email;
                // This would be where I would place my code displaying the items from the patient.intervencoes list
                found = true;
                break;
            }
```

Which control should I use and how do I display the items from the patient.intervencoes (list)? Thank you!

Comment: ListBox seems sensible; can't you do it this way:
lstbx.Add('intervention')?
Is "intervencoes" a ListBox member of the Paciente class? Is "pacientes" a generic list of the Paciente class?

Comment: Pacientes is the class which contains intervencoes, which is a List<string>. And no, I'm not able to do listbox.Add or listbox.Items.Add(patient.intervencoes) because it is a List<string>, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my response not being specific to the code you posted, but I think what will help you is something like this:

```
        //using System.Linq;
        patient.intervencoes.ForEach(var => ListBoxOnPageOrWPFForm.Items.Add(var));
```

With Null checking:

```
//using System.Linq;
        List<String> Items = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", null, null };
        Items.Where(var => var != null).ToList().ForEach(var => lbItems.Items.Add(var));
```

Or

If your view is in a cshtml page:

```
@Html.ListBox("Items", new SelectList(Model.intervencoes ), "")
```

Comment: I'm getting insivible values on the ListBox. There's the code when I .Add something to the list. [link](http://i.imgur.com/VVubbpz.png)

Comment: that would be because some 'intervencoes. are null, I've updated the snippet.